# PHP scrapy cURL request not working

Tags: php, ajax, curl, post

I am implementing a scrapy spider to crawl a website that contains real estate offers. The site contains a telephone number to the real estate agent, which can be retreived be an ajax post request.

To get a phone number I have to get ID from URL, next get from source csrfToken and send this with POST by special URL with ID. This method was working good but since yesterday not working.

My code:

```
    $urlSite = "https://www.otodom.pl/mazowieckie/oferta/piekne-mieszkanie-na-mokotowie-do-wynajecia-ID3ezHA.html";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSite);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match("/csrfToken = '(.+?)'/", $result, $output_array);
    preg_match("/ID(.+?).html/", $urlSite, $output_array_id);

    $token = $output_array[1];
    $id = $output_array_id[1];

    $url = "https://www.otodom.pl/ajax/mazowieckie/misc/contact/phone/" . $id . "/";

    $headers = [
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Length: 74',
        'Host: www.otodom.pl',
        'Referer: ' . $urlSite,
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36'
    ];

    $data = array(
        'CSRFToken' => $token
        );

    $data_string = http_build_query($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $phone = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $phone;
```

Please help me, I am working for this a few hours and nothing.

Comment: If it used to work, then probably they changed something. Like the HTML or some login issue, or they just blocked you. Try from another IP address and see if it works.

Comment: You need javascript, which culr doesn't support, try using selenium or similar

Comment: I was trying send this request by REST Client Chrome and still nothing...

Comment: `{"status":"error","message":"Spróbuj wykonać operację ponownie. Jeśli to nie pomoże, sprawdź czy masz włączoną obsługę JavaScript w przeglądarce."}`

Comment: I have the same answer, I think that phone number is protect in serwer... Corect answer is {"value":["515 174 616"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {"status":"error","message":"Spróbuj wykonać operację ponownie. Jeśli
> to nie pomoże, sprawdź czy masz włączoną obsługę JavaScript w
> przeglądarce."}

As I mentioned on my comment, you need JavaScript in order to get the phone number. One way to achieve this is using [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), here's a python example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver = 'C:/path_to/geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = geckodriver)
driver.get("https://www.otodom.pl/mazowieckie/oferta/piekne-mieszkanie-na-mokotowie-do-wynajecia-ID3ezHA.html")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("phone-spoiler").click()
time.sleep(2)
print driver.find_element_by_class_name("phone-number").text
# 515 174 616
```

---

**Notes:**

1 - Install Selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

2 - Download the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
3 - Replace `C:/path_to` with the `path` where you saved `geckodriver.exe`.
4 - Add `C:/path_to` to your environment.
5 - Restart your system.
6 - Run `python name_of_script.py` and the phone number will be displayed.

**The steps above assume that you're using a windows machine**.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I still thinking why not working with REST Client.

Comment: Because you need **javascript**, which curl doesn't have.

Comment: I can't click vote 1+ because of my low reputation, but I was click the accept answer. Thank you again for your help!